# Use regex to find a phrase UP TO 16 characters? (php)

Tags: php, regex, string

Little problem I'm facing. I've got a long string that has many words in it, and I'm trying to split it up, but most parts of the string have a start and end to reference to that is static, however this one only has an end, and the actual bit of string I'm trying to get is dynamic, but it is up to 16 characters, it could be less and the amount of words in the phrase is unknown.

Example:

```
Name: John Smith Occupation: Doctor Currently Busy Gender: Male
```

I want to get "Currently Busy" on it's own without getting the end of the other string before.

But I also want to use the same code to get "Not Yet Here" from this string:

```
Name: John Smith Occupation: Doctor Not Yet Here Gender: Male
```

I can't find a way, and I don't even know if it's possible so hopefully someone here could help me out.

Comment: Also, I can't use 'Doctor' as a reference as this could also change to potentially more than 1 word.

Comment: Something like this should work: `'Occupation: \w+ (.*?) Gender'`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is one that RegEx may not be able to solve. If the value of "occupation" can be one or more words, and it's directly succeeded by another value that could be one or more words, then how would you tell the two phrases apart, as a human?

I'm hoping that at the very least, you have a set of known `Occupation` values. If that's the case, then you can craft your expression like this:

```
(?<=Doctor |Nurse ).*(?= Gender)
```

The `(?<=...)` and `(?=...)` bits are lookbehind and lookahead assertions that essentially say "make sure that the expression `Doctor |Nurse` appears before the matched phrase (but do not match that part of it), and that the expression `Gender` appears after the matched phrase (but also do not match that part of it)."

See this in action: http://regexr.com?34buq

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I have don't have a list of values. However, the Occupation values can be in capitals if that is anything to go with, I'm trying to make it work but still can't get it right.

Comment: I think essentially what I need in regex is something that says 'Look for a word in capitals, match what is after it, but before `Gender`' Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe a better question to ask, then, is where are you getting these strings, and can you *change* them? If you're creating and storing these yourself, maybe you can do so in a more efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant way, but here's a solution:

```
$string = 'Name: John Smith Occupation: Doctor Currently Busy Gender: Male';
$groups = array_filter(preg_split('/\s?\w+:\s?/', $string));
// Split by [\s? => optional space][\w+ => characters a-zA-Z0-9_][:][\s? => optional space]

// $groups[2] contains 'Doctor Currently Busy'
$pieces = explode(' ', $groups[2]);
$pieces = array_reverse($pieces);
$length = 0;$i = 0;$c = count($pieces);$result = array(); // We need this for the loop
// $c and $i are to preserve the first word if the length of all words are < 16 !

foreach($pieces as $piece){
    $length += strlen($piece);
    $i++;
    if($length <= 16 && $c != $i){
        $result[] = $piece;
    }else{
        break;
    }
}

$result = array_reverse($result);
$final_result = implode(' ', $result);
echo $final_result; // Currently Busy
```